# Oracle 9i import error IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 3113

Tags: oracle, import, errors

I try to import a schema in my database 9i of copy which is a clone of the original from where I made the export 9i also and when trying to import the schema after many hours gives the following error:

> IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 3113:
>    "DECLARE  SREC DBMS_STATS.STATREC; BEGIN SREC.MINVAL := 'C20537'; SREC.MAXVA"
>    "L := 'C23524'; SREC.EAVS := 0; SREC.CHVALS := NULL; SREC.NOVALS := DBMS_STA"
>    "TS.NUMARRAY(454,455,....
>
> IMP-00003: ORACLE error 3113 encountered
>   ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
>   IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

The exp command is:

```
exp system/nnnnn CONSISTENT=y OWNER=myschema FILE=/path/backup_schema.dmp log=/path/backup_schema.log BUFFER=30720
```

The imp command is:

```
imp system/nnnn FROMUSER=myschema TOUSER=myschema FILE=/ path/backup_schema.dmp LOG=/path/backup_schema.log BUFFER = 536870912
```

I have searched and can not find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Did you try to specify `FULL=Y` while importing data? If not, do so. I'm not saying that it'll help, but - won't cost much to test it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORA-03113` is a generic error encountered when your database server process was terminated with a critical error. You can find more details in the database alert log. I guess you will see an `ORA-07445` error there.

As we do not know these details, all I see is that your error is related to importing statistics. I would try to run this import without importing statistics by specifying `STATISTICS=none`.

[STATISTICS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1005605)

> - NONE
>
> Do not import or recalculate the database optimizer statistics.

Then after the import you can gather statistics as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick response, I'm really short of time in this task, I'll try that option and comment, again thank you very much

Comment: I used the imp with indexes = n and it is importing much faster, the doubt that I now have is how to re-create all those indexes again since they are so many ... how can I import the indexes or recreate them ???

Comment: @ArnaldoRaxach And how is it related to the original question? You can use the `INDEXFILE` option to generate the DDL statements for indexes in a seperate file: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1005500